# Concatenating within a groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Let's say I have the following data of user stays at a hotel:

```
             end               start       uid
0 2014-01-02 00:00:00 2014-01-01 00:00:00    1
1 2014-01-04 00:00:00 2014-01-02 00:00:00    1
2 2014-02-02 00:00:00 2014-02-01 00:00:00    1
3 2014-01-02 00:00:00 2014-01-01 00:00:00    3
```

And I would like to concatenate consecutive stays that differ by 1 day or less (of the same user), effectively creating the following dataframe:

```
             end               start       uid
0 2014-01-04 00:00:00 2014-01-01 00:00:00    1
2 2014-02-02 00:00:00 2014-02-01 00:00:00    1
3 2014-01-02 00:00:00 2014-01-01 00:00:00    3
```

The first step would be to `groupby("uid")`. But how do I iterate through the rows of every group so that I can do this concatenation using the pandas toolbox?

For your convenience, here is a minimal initialization of the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
data = pd.DataFrame([{"uid":1,"start":datetime(year=2014,month=1,day=1),"end":datetime(year=2014,month=1,day=2)},{"uid":1,"start":datetime(year=2014,month=1,day=2),"end":datetime(year=2014,month=1,day=4)},{"uid":1,"start":datetime(year=2014,month=2,day=1),"end":datetime(year=2014,month=2,day=2)},{"uid":3,"start":datetime(year=2014,month=1,day=1),"end":datetime(year=2014,month=1,day=2)}])
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I solved this, without using any vectorization or special panda features.
Also, this assumes the data is sorted on start,end.

```
data["discard"] = False

grouped = data.groupby("uid")
uids = data.uid.unique()
maxdiff = 24 * 60 * 60
parts = []
for uid in uids:
    group = grouped.get_group(uid)

    for x in range(1,len(group)):
        prev = group.end.iloc[x-1]
            curr = group.start.iloc[x]
        difference = int((curr-prev).total_seconds())
        if difference<maxdiff:
            group.start.iloc[x] = group.start.iloc[x-1]
            group.discard.iloc[x-1] = True

    parts.append(group)

new_df = pd.concat(parts)
new_df = new_df[new_df.discard==False]
del new_df["discard"]
print new_df
```